# I must re-open or edit this main.py, or Outline said "No symbols found in document in main.py" when I start vscode in the morning

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

VSCode Version: 1.52.1

OS Version: Ubuntu 18.04

Steps to Reproduce:

1. start the vscode with a python script already opened.
2. I must re-open or edit this main.py, or Outline said "No symbols
   found in document in main.py" when I start vscode in the morning

How should I make vscode automatically show the outline, when I open vscode with a python script already opened at last time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reproduced the problem you described:

[image]

The reason is that the content of "OUTLINE" in VSCode is provided by "Python Language Service", and its trigger condition is to open the file. When we reopen the last opened and staying Python file, "OUTLINE" is already open but "Python language service" has not been loaded yet, we need to open the file to trigger this function to be displayed.

If you don't want to reopen the file, it is recommended that you open and stay in other python files before closing VSCode.

I submitted this question and let us expect it to have a better solution.
Github link: [Reopen VSCode, "OUTLINE" does not work for the last opened file.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15102)